# My for loop sequence is not ending with the perimeters are met to end

Tags: c, for-loop

For the below code I created a RNG and ask the user to input a number from one to 20 until they guess the correct number. When they guess the correct number the printf prints the correct text so I know `guesses[i] == randomNumber`

I would think that the for loop would terminate since now `guesses[i] != randomNumber` no longer holds a true value. The loop is not terminating and continues to ask the user to guess.

Am I missing something here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t t;
    srand(time(&t));
    int randomNumber = (rand() % 19) + 1;
    int guesses[30] = {0};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; guesses[i] != randomNumber; i++)
    {
        printf("Hello master, I will grant you 3 wishes if you can guess what number I have selected between 1 and 20: ");
        scanf("%d", &guesses[i]);

        if (guesses[i] == randomNumber) {
            printf("It took you %d guesses to guess correct but I lied I cannot grant you any wishes, have a nice day. \n\n", i + 1);
        }
        else if(guesses[i] < randomNumber) {
        printf("You guessed too low, try a higher number. \n\n");
        }
        else if(guesses[i] > randomNumber) {
        printf("You guessed too high, try a lower number. \n\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user inputs its guess, `i` increases by the loop increment instruction, and now your condition is applied to `guess[i]` which is actually the next `i` not the input user.

Comment: A simple fix is to get rid of the `i++` and change the condition to `guesses[i++]  != randomNumber`.

Comment: Another thing, try to make a limit on your loop because I may input a wrong number for more than 30 times, which will result in an index out of bound exception.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO..
I believe that testing the condition (`guesses[i] != randomNumber`) happens before advancing i (`i++`), so you are actually testing against `i` that was already advanced by 1

You can either try to use `++i` instead of `i++`

OR

You can use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop:

```
i = 0;
while (guesses[i] != randomNumber && i < 30) {
    i++;
    printf("Hello master, I will grant you 3 wishes if you can guess what number I have selected between 1 and 20: ");
    scanf("%d", &guesses[i]);

    if (guesses[i] == randomNumber) {
        printf("It took you %d guesses to guess correct but I lied I cannot grant you any wishes, have a nice day. \n\n", i + 1);
    }
    else if(guesses[i] < randomNumber) {
        printf("You guessed too low, try a higher number. \n\n");
    }
    else if(guesses[i] > randomNumber) {
        printf("You guessed too high, try a lower number. \n\n");
    }
}
```

Note how I also added a test for `i < 30` to not get out of the array index bounds

Comment: Thanks for the welcome I tried ++i already with the same results.  Also tried a while loop instead :-/ I'm guessing my syntax is off in some way with my while loop because then it returns a you guessed like 80 some times when I only guessed 4 times lol

Comment: @Tim - I added a code snipped to my answer with the while loop.. let me know if it works for you